# Búsquedas filtradas con marcadores

Tags: php, php7, pdo

me ha sido útil información de su página y como ya leí, en una instrucción sql no se necesita poner marcadores entre comillas simples, pero tengo una duda, ¿Cómo se logra juntar un marcador con el símbolo `"%"` ?

Ejemplo:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE campo LIKE '%$busqueda%' " ;
```

Donde `$busqueda` es un parámetro dado

Yo quisiera usar marcador junto con % pero no me funciona el query

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE campo LIKE :marcador% ";
```

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo la pregunta, podría ayudar lo siguiente?

```
<?php
$busqueda = "manzana";
echo "SELECT * FROM table WHERE campo LIKE '%$$busqueda'" ;
```

En todo caso, ¿podrías guiarme para poder ayudarte?

Comment: Excelente, tiene lógica lo mencionado, gracias por la aclaración

Answer (score 0):

Colocar el uso de *wildcards* junto a un marcador de nombre, de este modo:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE campo LIKE :marcador% ";
```

Genera un error de sintaxis como lo podemos ver imprimiendo la consulta con `debugDumpParams();` que mostraría esto:

```
SQL: [50] SELECT * FROM table WHERE campo LIKE :marcador
Sent SQL: [50] SELECT * FROM table WHERE campo LIKE 'valorDinamico'%
Params:  1
Key: Name: [7] :marcador
paramno=-1
name=[7] ":marcador"
is_param=1
param_type=2
NULL
```

**¿Pero cuál es el error?**

> Si notas al usar el *wildcard* directo en el marcador de nombre, genera esta sintaxis: `':marcador'%`, es decir deja dicho símbolo fuera de las comillas lo cual es un error pues así no se escribe dicha condición.

**Solución**

> A la variable que vas a interpolar con el marcador de nombre, será a la que le coloques el uso del *wildcard*, quedando de este modo:

```
$variable = "valorAComparar%";
```

Ahora usándola dentro de tu query se vería de este modo:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE campo LIKE :marcador";
```

Si de nuevo hacemos un volcado en línea de comandos de la consulta anterior veremos lo siguiente:

```
SQL: [50] SELECT * FROM table WHERE campo LIKE :marcador
Sent SQL: [50] SELECT * FROM table WHERE campo LIKE 'valorDinamico%'
Params:  1
Key: Name: [7] :marcador
paramno=-1
name=[7] ":marcador"
is_param=1
param_type=2
NULL
```

Como notas, ahora la sintaxis es: `'%valorDinamico'` con lo cual se podrá llevar a cabo la comparación que deseas.

Tu código final debería ser similar a este:

```
$variable = "valorAComparar%";
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE campo LIKE :marcador";
```

**Referencias**

- [`debugDumpParams PHP 7.2`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php)
- [`wild-cards` en MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html)