# Implemento buscador con Like, falla

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
function buscarMarca(PDO $db) {

  $buscar=$_GET['buscador'];
$consulta= $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM marcas WHERE nombre LIKE '%:buscador%'");

    $consulta->bindValue(':buscador',$buscar, PDO::PARAM_STR);

   $consulta->execute();

    $marca= $consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $marca;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que leas [Te he votado negativamente porque es solamente código](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/107347), también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Answer (score 1):

- El **marcador de nombre** no esta interpretando de modo correcto los *wildcards* con los que intentas establecer la condición
- Saca la condición del cuerpo de la búsqueda y asignalo a una variable para que posteriormente sea esta variable la que pases al cuerpo de tu consulta SQL de este modo:
- A la nueva variable a la que igualas con la variable que almacena el valor que le llega por **`GET`** del usuario concatenale ambos signos de `wildcards`

Tu código:

```
function buscarMarca(PDO $db) {

    $buscar=$_GET['buscador'];
    $condicion = "%".$buscar."%";
    $consulta= $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM marcas WHERE nombre LIKE :buscador'");

    $consulta->bindValue(':buscador',$condicion, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $consulta->execute();

    $marca= $consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $marca;
}
```

Para mayor referencia de lo que pasa [checa esta otra respuesta que dí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/275523/b%c3%basquedas-filtradas-con-marcadores/275537#275537) es muy similar a la tuya